# Firefox Quantum - Can't hide focus ring on input

Tags: css, firefox

I'm writing a website that uses a rich Material Design theme on top of Bootstrap 4. So far I have been able to make all the browser chrome match the site at least somewhat (Chrome's autofill indicator being the most difficult to date), but ever since I started developing in Firefox Quantum, I'm running into difficulties hiding the focus ring around input fields:

[image: unfocused input field]
[image: focus ring around search field]

According to the MDN docs, I should be able to apply the `outline: none` property to `input:focus` or `input:-moz-focusring`, however none of these seem to work. I can see the property showing up in the style inspector, and Firefox doesn't show that it's being overridden by anything, but the focus ring still shows up.

I understand it's important to have indication of focus, however seeing as I already have my own clear indication of focus, I would prefer to hide the browser-provided one as it interferes with my styling.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Trying to reproduce this in JSFiddle...I've referenced all relevant styles I can find and still can't reproduce it. Figures...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so, I solved this while trying to reproduce it in JSFiddle (which I wouldn't have been able to do). It's ridiculous.

On my site, I'm compiling Bootstrap and Material Design from source along with my own SCSS so that I can override the colors and options for the two. It turns out that Material Design overrides the `enable-shadows` option for Bootstrap, but *only if the SCSS is referenced for both*, so it's impossible to reproduce in JSFiddle (where the SCSS has already been compiled to CSS).

The offending rule is in Bootstrap's `mixins/_forms.scss` file under `form-control-focus`. It's new in the latest minor version of Bootstrap, apparently, because I've tested in Chrome since updating and the rectangle shows up there, too (whereas it did not before updating Bootstrap). The rule won't show up in the inspector because opening the inspector unfocuses the control, and the :focus state doesn't trigger the JS event to let Bootstrap know it's focused, which led me to believe it was browser chrome highlighting the control.